# What wiki can we use on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: software-installation

Does anyone knows what wiki can be supported on a raspberry pi?

I am about to try this one : https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki

Is there a better candidate?

Comment: kiwix-plug can be used on a raspberry pi as /viewer/ for any wiki engine (though designed for MediaWiki). Editing features are yet to develop, though. :) http://www.kiwix.org/wiki/Kiwix-plug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [LionWiki](http://lionwiki.0o.cz/index.php?page=Main%20page).

From the website:

> LionWiki is a minimalist Wiki engine programmed in PHP. It is
>   extensible, templatable, file based (it doesn't need database like
>   MySQL) and requires just one file to function. It is suitable for
>   small websites, personal notebooks or journals.